# having trouble with sql

Tags: php, sql, pdo

been almost a year since i have had to muck around with databases, and as a self taught starter, am having a bit of trouble.
Below is the part of code that is not working, above this is the successful connection to server.
From here it is failing to update and i am not sure why.
On my system, i do have a working PDO connection string if you feel that it should be done in PDO.
At this point i am poking holes in the air.
Appreciate your time.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE bfl SET gamerid="?", name="?", age="?",location"?", email="?", console="?"WHERE team="?" ");



 $stmt->bindParam(1, $gamerid);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $name);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $age);
    $stmt->bindParam(4, $location);
    $stmt->bindParam(5, $email);
    $stmt->bindParam(6, $cosole);
    $stmt->bindParam(7, $team);

$stmt->execute(array($gamerid,$name,$age,$location,$email,$co‌​nsole,$team);
```

Comment: That's the `insert` syntax not the `update` syntax. `mysql_*` also won't mix with `pdo` you should use `pdo` and parameterize the query. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html for update syntax. Additionally variables in single quotes aren't variables. So there are a lot of issues here you're going to need to work out..

Comment: so SET gamerid="$gamerid", name="$name", ect..
my pdo ability is virtually non existant

Comment: Your `mysql_*` doesn't seem to be that far along so might as well fix the ship before it sinks. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php Use `?`s for all the values then pass the values with the binding function or in the execute as an array. e.g. `$sth->execute(array($gamerid,$name,$age,$location,$email,$console, $team))` and the prepare like `$pdo->prepare('UPDATE bfl SET  gamerid = ?,name = ?,age =?,location=?,email=?,console=? WHERE team= ?')`

Comment: It should be done in PDO or mysqli. PHP [removed the mysql_ functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) in 7.0. You should also [switch to prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/5828/pdo/2685/preventing-sql-injection-with-parameterized-queries). I'll bet another reason your query is failing due to your concatenating data

Comment: something along these lines

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE bfl SET (gamerid="?", name="?", age="?",location"?", email="?"console="?") WHERE team="?" ");'$stmt->bindParam(1, $gamerid);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $name);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $age);
$stmt->bindParam(4, $location);
$stmt->bindParam(5, $email);
$stmt->bindParam(6, $cosole);
$stmt->bindParam(7, $team);

$sth->execute(array($gamerid,$name,$age,$location,$email,$co‌​nsole,$team);

Comment: Have you added any error output? We still don't know why MySQL doesn't like it

Comment: under advisement I am looking at PDO, but the above code is what I have peiced together after reading a page, and most likely full of holes... any advise would be helpful... still getting syntax errors here, not even through to sql yet

Comment: there seems to be a problem with prepare statement

Comment: I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. That mysql syntax is the `insert` syntax, not update.
2. Use `PDO` not `mysql_*`.
3. Use parameterized queries, not concatenated.
4. Placeholders don't get quoted.
5. Bind or bind in the execute, don't do both.
6. Don't put parenthesis around the whole inner query.

Put together you get:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE bfl
                       SET gamerid=?,
                       name=?,
                       age=?,
                       location?,
                       email=?,
                       console=?
                       WHERE team=?');
$stmt->execute(array($gamerid,$name,$age,$location,$email,$co‌​nsole, $team));
```

Also look at using error reporting, http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php, this will help you in the future.

Comment: ahh, so if I bound each one, I would just have to execute();